# How to get all childs active-storage attachments in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

let's say there are 2 models.

user model:

has_many :posts

post model:

belongs_to :user

has_many_attached :files, dependent: :destroy

what I want is simply all files of the user. something like:

has _may :post_files , through: posts, class_name: "XXX"

or any other way which can give me all the files of the user.

so I want all files of all posts which belong to the user. like user.post_files

Comment: Hint, `has_many_through` may be your friend

Comment: I can't find has_many_through in rails docs, can you send me a link or show me the correct code?

Comment: Sure, section 2.4 https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: I've added an answer, see if that fits your needs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thank you all for your answers. I found the solution.

`has_many_attached :files` actually sets two has_many relationships:

`has_many :files_attachments`  and
`has_many :files_blobs`

So in user.rb (parent model) we can simply have:

`has_many :files_attachments, through: :posts`

and in this way, you can have user.files_attachments to get all files of posts for one user.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how the structure should be

user.rb <-- User model

```
has_many :posts
```

post.rb <-- Post model

```
belongs_to :user 
has_many_attached :files
```

this way you can do

```
Post.post_files
```

or

```
Post.with_attached_files.find(params[:id])
```

In conclusion.

The attachments  belong to the Post, not to the User, so there is no need to make any call to User model

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question. The user has many posts. so I want all fils of all posts which belong to the user. like user.post_files

Answer (score 2):

Your post model acts as an xref table between users and attached files right?
You have defined a user as having many posts and a post as having many attached files. Using `has_many through:` will allow a user to see all the attached files for a post

user model:

```
Class User < ...
  has_many :posts
  has_many attached_files, through: :posts
```

post model:

```
Class Post < ...
    belongs_to :user
    has_many_attached :files, dependent: :destroy

Class AttchedFiles < ...
  belongs_to :post
```

This enables you to do things like

```
 User.first.attached_files
```

Which will return all the attached files for the user returned by the User.first declaration

Which I believe is what you were looking for

Comment: thank you for your answer, I didn't really understand what should be Class AttchedFiles, I have tried it but didn't really work. i attached imaged of models in my question, please check

Comment: your answer was close but attached_files should be files_attachments